# Using my Dads music on my iPhone?

Tags: iphone, itunes, music

When my Dad died last year we put his iphone away in a drawer for safe keeping, because his music was very important to him and obviously we didn't want to lose it.

The phone is getting hard to hold a charge now and I'm wondering if there is a way to put his music into my iPhone? I bought a 64gig iPhone to have enough room to fit it all on but now I've realised it isn't as easy as I first thought.

Is there a way to do this or do I just have to hope the battery never completely fails on his phone?

Answer (score 1):

There is no 'official' way to pull music from any iDevice back to a computer, but there are many unofficial apps that can do it.

The basic idea is that you get the music off the iDevice & into iTunes, from where you can then keep it or re-sync it to your own device.

I know of no way to do this directly from phone to phone, you must have a computer as an intermediary.

Googling "copy music from iPhone to computer" will give you more variants on applications than you would know what to do with - & also I don't know what computer platform you have, so I'm linking to a LifeHacker article explaining how to do it on Windows, Mac & Linux.

[How to Copy Music from Your iPhone, iPad, or iPod touch to Your Computer for Free](http://lifehacker.com/5869827/how-to-copy-music-from-your-iphone-ipad-or-ipod-touch-to-your-computer-for-free)